# Как отправить данные с одного устройства на другое посредством nfc

Tags: java, android

В одном устройстве ввожу данные в приложении и отправляю другом устройству,
у другого устройства данные должны отобразиться в TextView

Как это реализовать?
Почитал документацию,посмотрел примеры, но там только как отправить данные, а как вот их отобразить на другом устройстве не написано.
В каком направлении копать?

Узнал, что нужно на 2-ом устройстве поймать Intent, как это сделать?